# Gwt, How to code the Right-ClickHandler for Label?

Tags: gwt, label, handler, right-click

Ok, for label, we got ClickHandler, ie, when we click on the label it will do something.

But I want to do something like Right-ClickHandler for Label, ie, when user right click on the label, it will do something.

Some people say put the widget into DeckPanel & do the RightClick Hanler on it. But if we have a lot of labels, then

does each label have to be put into a deck panel?

If that is the case then the code maybe complicated, so I want to do the RightClick handler for label just like i do normal ClickHandler. How to do do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am heavily recommending [**this example**](https://confluence.clazzes.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=425996) (Which is bit old but the right way to deal with context menu).

```
   lable.sinkEvents(Event.ONCONTEXTMENU);
    lable.addHandler(
      new ContextMenuHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onContextMenu(ContextMenuEvent event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          popupMenu.setPopupPosition(              //custom menu here
            event.getNativeEvent().getClientX(),
            event.getNativeEvent().getClientY());
          popupMenu.show();
    }
    }, ContextMenuEvent.getType())
```

**[Continue reading ....](http://codeinventions.blogspot.in/2014/07/context-menu-or-right-click-handler-in.html)**